# linker errors when integrating admob sdk into iOS app

Tags: ios, admob

I integrated Google's AdMob SDK into a working iPhone app.  I'm getting 12 errors that all start with 'Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error'.  The text of the error messages typically refer to a low level objective C object called from a google library.  For example:

*Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSInMemoryStoreType", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      +[GAIDataStore memoryContextWithModel:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)*

I thought I might not be linking a necessary framework but that all seems to be in order.  I followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ and my linked libraries tab looks like this:

[image: screenshot of linked libraries]

Unless I'm mistaken, it includes the frameworks that AdMob needs.  Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add all_load to the Other Linker Flags?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably just included the "add-ons" folder wholesale. Unfortunately that folder also includes the Google Analytics example project and binary. If you're not using analytics from there, I would remove the entire "GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta2" folder.

Comment: That was exactly it.  Thank you very much RajPara.  I love stack overflow.

Comment: in 6.12.0 there is no GA folder :(